# nesting c++ functions template and typename template

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I am trying to nest template in  c++17 where I want to template on functions but also on the arguments that these function can accept.

here is a minimal reproducing example of what I am trying to do.

At first I make a template on function. I have managed to do this part.

```
double add(double x, double y){return x+ y;}
double diff(double x, double y){return x - y;}

template <double fn1(double, double), double fn2(double, double)>
double combine(double x, double y) {

    return fn1(x, y) + fn2(x, y);
}
```

I manage to use it this way:

```
auto z = combine<add, diff>(x, y);
```

Now I would like to also use template to support difference floating point precision in the functions that I am passing.
So first I create a template on the add and diff functions

```
template <typename T>
T add(T x, T y){return x+ y;}
T diff(T x, T y){return x - y;}
```

But then I am stuck. How to I modify the combine function to work?
The first idea I had bellow does not work

```
template <typename T,T fn1(T, T), T fn2(T, T)>
T combine(T x, T y) {

    return fn1(x, y) + fn2(x, y);
}
```

Comment: Your code works: https://godbolt.org/z/xn9rh1hra You just have to adept the call side to the changed template.

Comment: I just recognized that `combine<float, add, diff>(3.2f, 7.2f)` also works. How did you call the function? Like in the example before? The new version has 3 template parameters, so adding the new first one works.

Comment: Yes I realise  after Bob__  comment that It was I typo that I mistook for a template error. Should I delete the question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> here is a minimal reproducing example of what I am trying to do

Well, not quite.

There's a missing `template <typename T>` before `T diff(T x, T y){return x - y;}` and it's not shown how the templated `combine` is called. If you try to use the same

```
auto z = combine<add, diff>(x, y);
```

The template parameter `T` can't be deduced.

You can either pass all the template parameters when calling combine:

```
float x = combine<float, add, diff>(1.0f, 3.14f); // -> 2
```

Or use an alias

```
auto& z = combine<double, add, diff>;

float x = z(3.5, 5.17); // -> 7
```

Se e.g.: https://godbolt.org/z/b1ETqbj9c

Comment: Thank you. So in the end it was just a typo and I though I was using template improperly. Sorry for wasting your time.